# Concatenation of square numbers is a square?

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics, square-numbers

Just a curiosity of mine.

If I define the $n^{th}$ concatenation number (denoted $Q_n$) to be the the concatenation of digits from the $1^{st}$ square number to the $n^{th}$, can $Q_n$ ever be square itself apart from $n=1$?

So for instance, $Q_1=1$, $Q_2=14$, $Q_3=149$, $Q_4=14916$. I have tested up to $Q_{14}$ and they were all not square numbers.

The only thing I can think of is that we could express $Q_n$ as a summation:

$$Q_n=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}i^2\times10^{\epsilon_{i.n}}$$ where $\epsilon_{i,n}$ depends on $i$ and $n$ and they are various integers.

How could I proceed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are very few squares, so it's not all that surprising to see a short list of (rather large) numbers that doesn't contain a square.

Comment: @lulu I agree! It would be interesting to know some properties about this list of numbers though.

Comment: According to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A019521),   
$Q_3=149$ is the only prime $Q_n$ up to $n=4000$

Comment: If we don't have to start with 1, then 49 works.

Comment: I think , this question has been recently asked (can concattenating the perfect squares ever lead to a perfect square ?). I do not remember exactly how far I checked whether we can arrrive at a perfect power at all , but such a perfect power must have thousands of digits hence I assume there is none.

Comment: Upto $n=3\cdot 10^4$ (concattenating the squares upto $n^2$) , there is no perfect power (except $1$ , if this counts at all which usually does not)

Comment: @Peter wow that's very interesting! is this result obtained by brute force computation? :)

Comment: For PARI/GP it is no problem to check even huge numbers whether they are a perfect power.

Comment: The question whether there is a further prime of that form might also be interesting. For the Smarandache numbers (the first $n$ positive integers are concattenated) , NO prime is known.

Comment: Concerning the primes : no further prime upto $n=4\ 800$

Comment: @Peter Thanks for sharing about Smarandache numbers, it was very interesting to read about it (maybe a typo in your comment as the internet says it is concat. of prime number?). One tiny observation I would add is that $Q_{2n}$ and $Q_{5n}$ are definitely composite numbers but I think that's rather obvious

Comment: @Peter And could I please ask when you said no further primes up to n=4800, we are talking about these $Q_n$ here right? not the Smarandache numbers? :)

Comment: With the numbers I checked upto $n=4\ 800$ I mean the numbers of the form $149162536\cdots$ . PFGW uses "Sm(n)" for the $n$-th Smarandachnumber (form $123456789101112\cdots$) , no prime is known and this has been tested very far. Finally , the Smarandache-Wellin numbers (if I remember the name right) concattenate the primes. No idea about search limits here.

Comment: In fact, I mean $Q_n$ , not the Smarandache numbers